# Is it possible to configure custom system tray icons in Ubuntu 17.04 desktop?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, system-tray

I have a Qt GUI application running on Ubuntu 17.04 with a custom desktop icon. Is it possible to have a custom icon display in the Ubuntu system tray at the top right?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-systray-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you have to set the custom icon as QIcon object for the QSystemTray object.
Sample Code

```
QSystemTrayIcon m_Tray = new QSystemTrayIcon(this); 
m_Tray->setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/customIcon.ico"));
m_Tray->show();
```

or pass the QIcon in constructor itself.

Comment: Can it be configured to have the icon there at start up?

Comment: @AnkurShah You mean splash screen?

Comment: Not sure what splash screen is

Comment: Does the icon need to be shown when the application starts?

Comment: I think he means starting the program minimzed (only the icon) when the OS starts

Comment: @FlorentUguet If that's the case, then he can start the app on startup with arguments "--startup", and in app he can check the arguments, if it matches then he can hide the app by calling hide() function on QMainWindow

Comment: But he has to provide show action in custom context menu for QSystemTrayIcon so that user can open the application from system tray